# I have a questions about using :source when building associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a problem when setting up associations in my rails project and wonder if anyone can help me with that??

I have three models: user, comment and event. And there are two kinds of users: organization and volunteer. I have problem when I tried to make `event.volunteers` and `volunteer.joined_events` work...
Here are how the models set up:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :organization, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :volunteer, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :event
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :organized_events, foreign_key: "organization_id", class_name: "Event"
    has_many :joined_events, through: :being_commented_comments, :source => :event
    has_many :commented_comments, foreign_key: "organization_id", class_name: "Comment"
    has_many :being_commented_comments, foreign_key: "volunteer_id", class_name: "Comment"
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :organization, class_name: "User"
    has_many :volunteers, through: :comments, source: "Volunteer"
    has_many :comments
end
```

And I keep getting errors like:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) "Event" in model Comment. Try 'has_many :joined_events, :through => :being_commented_comments, :source => <name>'. Is it one of organization, volunteer, or event?)
```

or

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError (Cannot have a has_many :through association 'User#joined_events' which goes through 'User#being_commented_comments' before the through association is defined.)
```

and I think the problem happens because I am not familiar enough with `:source`...Any suggestions would be super appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using `has_many through:` you must declare the association you are going through before the indirect association:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :organized_events, foreign_key: "organization_id", class_name: "Event"
  has_many :being_commented_comments, foreign_key: "volunteer_id", class_name: "Comment"
  has_many :joined_events, through: :being_commented_comments, source: :event
  has_many :commented_comments, foreign_key: "organization_id", class_name: "Comment"
end
```